# VBA function to include CDATA

Tags: vba, cdata

I have the following function to include cdata:

```
Function cdatasection()
    Dim objDom As DOMDocument
    Dim objKMLRootelement As IKMLDOMElement
    Dim objKMLelement As IKMLDOMElement
    Dim cdata As IKMLDOMCDATASection

    Set objDom = New DOMDocument
    Set objKMLRootelement = objDom.createElement("BalloonStyle")
    objDom.appendChild objKMLRootelement
    Set objKMLelement = objDom.createElement("text")
    objKMLRootelement.appendChild objKMLelement
    Set cdata = objDom.createCDATASection("text")
    cdata.Data = "<![CDATA[<b>Latitude = $[latitude]</b>?]]>;"
End Function
```

When I run the above, I am getting this error "User defined data type not found" for the function.

Comment: You need to either add a reference to your project or declare the items as objects and use CreateObject to set them.

Comment: What is `IKMLDOMElement`? do you mean `IXMLDOMElement` ? Also, your function doesn't return any value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes as Ripster says find the library reference.  From the VBA window Tools>References

For a list of relevant references see...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms763701%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

However, if you have a hard time tracking down the reference, replace all `Dim` Statements and `Set objDom = New DOMDocument` to...

```
Dim objDom as Object
Set objDom = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM") ' EDIT: If this does not work, try...
'Set objDom = CreateObject("MSXML22.DOMDocument.6.0")


Dim objKMLRootelement As Object
Dim objKMLelement As Object    
Dim cdata As Object
```

Comment: `Set objDOM = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument60")` surely? The `Microsoft` namespace predates `MSXML2` - see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/xmlteam/archive/2006/10/23/using-the-right-version-of-msxml-in-internet-explorer.aspx)

Comment: Yeah, assuming he has Vista and up that should work.  See edit.